# Can df.reset_index(drop=true) be set as default in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

when slicing a dataframe in Python Pandas it remembers the index of the rows. if you don't want this you can use df.reset_index(drop=true). However is there a way that this can be set to be the default? 
I always want to have my indexes reset.

Also what are situations where you want to remember the index?

Thanks

Comment: @bernie , thanks for the solution, however I think this is a bit to dangerous with regards to portability. Also if someone else writes a program who doesn't know I changed it, this can lead to big frustrations.

I hoped their would be some line of code which I could insert at the top.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default values by set `func_defaults`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame.reset_index.im_func.func_defaults = (None, True, False, 0, '')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 4)), columns=list("ABCD"), index=np.ones(10))
df.reset_index()
```